# Android Beacon Library - how to stop preservation file saving? "android-beacon-library-scan-state" is getting too big

Tags: android, altbeacon

I developed an app based on Android Beacon Library which runs fine for 1-2 days. Then it is just stop starting anymore I need to reinstall or clear its app data. It runs as a foreground service.
I figured out that  "android-beacon-library-scan-state" file is getting bigger and bigger (10beacons for few hours and it is around 10Mbytes) I thought first that I should use setRegionStatePersistenceEnabled(false) but it stops "org.altbeacon.beacon.service.monitoring_status_state" to be created not "android-beacon-library-scan-state".

```
I am ranging. This file is created after 1 hour used 12 beacons. <a href="https://wetransfer.com/downloads/464b91135dab99ebcc400a6c9008f60d20210116121500/f6c244">file</a>
```

Comment: Are you monitoring or ranging multiple regions?  Can you pull the file off of your device with ADB and share?

Comment: Ranging. Just expanded the original question.

Comment: Is your app using Eddystone-TLM or a custom beacon format that uses an "extra" data frame?  Since you are using a foreground service to scan continually, does your app set `beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);`?

Comment: Yes I scan Eddystone-TLM and Ruuvi high res formats. No, that line beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false); is not used. I have not seen in the examples... Can it be the reason?

Comment: It solved the problem. Thank you very much! Please "answer" so I can accept as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using a foreground service, make sure you have set `beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)`.  This will prevent the system from persisting the MAC addresses of all devices transmitting Eddystone-TLM in hopes of lining them up with a subsequent detection.  This persistence is what caused your file to grow to an unreasonable size.